# how to load a page through a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

please help to fix the script.

```
import pprint
import requests

import bs4

topicsWatch = [
                'http://forum.saransk.ru/',
                'http://forum.saransk.ru/topic/194169-v-kakuiu-sportivnuiu-sektciiu-mozhno-zapisat-reben/',
]

#1
html = requests.get(topicsWatch[0])
print(topicsWatch[0], end='\n')
print(html.status_code )    #OK
print(html.raise_for_status())

#2
html = requests.get(topicsWatch[1])
print(topicsWatch[1], end='\n')
print(html.status_code )    #?????????????
print(html.raise_for_status())
```

there are two blocks of code. "# 1" and "2". 
block "# 1" will return the response "200" 
block "# 2" will return the response "404".

I do not understand this. both pages actually exist:

```
http://forum.saransk.ru/
http://forum.saransk.ru/topic/194169-v-kakuiu-sportivnuiu-sektciiu-mozhno-zapisat-reben/
```

how to do so in both cases, returns a "200"?

output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
http://forum.saransk.ru/
200
None
http://forum.saransk.ru/topic/194169-v-kakuiu-sportivnuiu-sektciiu-mozhno-zapisat-reben/
404
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\5_forum_new\q.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(html.raise_for_status())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 773, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the second page (http://forum.saransk.ru/topic/194169-v-kakuiu-sportivnuiu-sektciiu-mozhno-zapisat-reben/) doesn't exist.

You get a nice error page saying that it doesn't exist but that is a default page. You get this same page also for http://forum.saransk.ru/topic/invalid-page - for example.

For that page specifically, they use the nginx-server and you can define there which content you want to show if a non existent page is requested with the [error_page - property](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) other web-servers have similar settings so that you wouldn't end up with an old ugly 404 page.